# Search recent data with mysql, Full text search old data with solr

Tags: php, mysql, solr

I build a web application in php and mysql. I want to search data doing full text search on 3-4 table. I'm considering for it  lucene solr project.

My question is:
Is it correct save today data in separate mysql table, then and it make a simple search only for that today data and if it find enything, it try query on lucene for full text search but in old data( from yesterday to past) ?

My web app save data in mysql but I want that user can full text search on that data. I can run a job that 4 times for day import data from msql to lucene solr, but if data on mysql change by user and solr doesn't already start importing and indexing data, user should be able in any case to search and see recent modified data.

What is the  best approach for integrate lucene solr with mysql and php?

Is it possible send a modify command to solr ftom php  for update data that user changed but be sure to commit data on solr only if a mysql 
 transaction go well done, so finaly i have commited data in mysql and commited data in lucene and if something goes wrong on web application rollback all as in mysql as in solr?

Comment: Please consider editing your question to include details about your intended scope for this project. How many rows are in your tables now? How many per day. How much history do you want to store in Solr/Lucene? My feeling is that mysql is a engineered solution for storing data (and querying) very efficiently with the trade-off that you must used typed data for your column defs, data must be clean going in, etc. Search engines are designed first for generality of data, 2nd for speed of search, and 3rd for efficient use of disk and RAM (compared to DBs). Do a lot of research! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking of implementing Lucene, the number of table does not matter. As per for the best approach, I would say to implement Zend's [Zend Search Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html).

The lucene library like [`Zend Search Lucene`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html) have there own mechanism of tokenizing the data and search through them. They are basically fed with data from the database, from which they will build the search files and store them separately, if something goes wrong, then just *rebuild the search*.

About the possibility of update the Lucene data when the database gets updated, relies completely on what solution you implement. [`Zend Search Lucene`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html) on other hand, can do it.

Comment: I want do full text search on data that are store in mysql, but I don't know how Keep it sync with apache solr.I aldo read that zend_lucene it is slow, it is more profitable use apache solr.

Comment: @paganotti, Apache's is good to, but Zend's Lucene is not slow, from my past experiences.

Answer (score 0):

You might run into inconsistant search results with some of your hits coming from MySql and some coming from Solr.

Think about either:

1. Doing all your fulltext searching in MySQL
2. Doing all your fulltext searching in Solr

Implementing Solr means keeping the data synced up between MySQL->Solr and an additional piece of infrastructure.

See if you can do what you need just by using MySQL's `FULLTEXT` indexing and `MATCH() AGAINST()` query clauses.  It will keep your application a lot simpler.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html